# Ruby script start from a specific line or method

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, argv

Let's say i have a script:

```
!#usr/bin/ruby

# step 1
puts "That's first"
# some code

#step 2
puts "That's second"
# some code
```

Is there a way to pass ARGV to script that will start execution from a specific line (or step, or class, or whatever)?
For example executing `$ ruby script.rb -s 2` will start from second step.

I have a thought about parsing the argument with `if\else`, but in this case script will become much more complicated and not DRY at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways as the answer of max shows you, but you shouldn't do it.
There were questions about a goto statement for Ruby before you know.
Why should you go back to the techniques used in BASIC ? Show us a usage and we'll show you better ways.

If you are begining with Ruby and programming you can just use a procedural way of programming like

```
def print_a
  puts "a"
end
```

and later on, no matter where the line of "puts a" has moved to in between you last update

```
print_a
```

If you are more experienced you'll use this with a combination of Object Oriented or Functional way of programming.

One acceptional use comes me in to mind:  conditional require 's or load's

```
if condition
  require ./mycode_only_to be_executed_in_this_case.rb'
end
```

Hope I got you rethinking your question..

EDIT after comment op

The example you refer to isn't DRY, that is the first thing that I' m noticing.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself for a definition of DRY

Here what I would make of it, I still use a methods to envelop my code so that it is code that I can reuse and has only one purpose and is testable: connect to a site. No duplicate code, so DRY.

```
require 'watir'

def goto_site site
  a = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
  a.goto site
  # a lot of code down here
  a.close
end

goto_site 'site.com'
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, your approach is deep. In my case i have a script that runs a watir webdriver and checks several instances. [Example here](https://repl.it/EfU2/1). So i was wondering is there a way to execute script from a spepcific step if there's no need to check previous.

Comment: I EDITed my answer, please have a look at it.

Comment: It depends if `# a lot of code down here` is the same from one method to another.

Comment: @peter: You'd need a different structure for DRY, since `goto_site(site)` would need to call a different code depending on `site`. Right now, it only saves a couple of lines, and doesn't really help with the original question.

Comment: @EricDuminil I would have to see the rest of the code to decide how to keep it DRY but what matters is that methods are suited here and not a goto line solution, the DSL solution of Eric is also some kind of methods, Max solution is interesting but not advisable, they both have a +1 from me

Answer (score 4):

Here's a program `run_from_line.rb` which accepts three arguments: path and start line, and end line. End line is optional and defaults to -1.

```
#/usr/bin/env ruby

path = ARGV.shift
program_text = File.readlines(path)
start_line = ARGV.shift.to_i;
end_line = ARGV.shift || '-1'
end_line = end_line.to_i

selected_code = program_text[start_line..end_line].join
eval selected_code
```

With this script at `test.rb`:

```
puts "line 0"
puts "line 1"
puts "line 2"
```

Testing:

```
> ruby run_from_line.rb test.rb 1
line 1
line 2

> ruby run_from_line.rb test.rb 1 1
line 1
```

If you want to make this a system-wide script, run `chmod a+x run_from_line.rb` then `sudo mv run_from_line.rb /usr/local/sbin`

Comment: `shift` is pretty heavy-handed. Why not `path = ARGV[0]` or `path, start_l, end_l = ARGV`?

Comment: People are a lot of time confused because of ARGV interfering with gets.chomp

Comment: How are those two related? One is from STDIN, the other from ARGV.

Comment: That is an interesting point, `Kernel#gets` does, but I've never seen anyone confuse those two things. It's actually a neat feature because you can specify input files via the command-line even for programs that don't explicitly allow it.

Comment: Ive seen a few people confused because their gets.chomp is not pausing to ask for input. Thats a cool tip though

Answer (score 4):

[Bad things](https://xkcd.com/292/) happen when you use GOTO.

Here's a proposal that could solve your problem in a bit more elegant way :

Define your steps in 'define_steps.rb' :

```
# define_steps.rb
#####################################################
@steps = []

def step(i, &block)
  @steps[i] = block
end

def launch_steps!(min = 0, max = @steps.size - 1)
  @steps[min..max].each.with_index(min) do |block, i|
    if block
      puts "Launching step #{i}"
      block.call
    end
  end
end
#####################################################

step 1 do
  puts 'Step 1 with lots of code'
end

step 2 do
  puts 'Step 2 with lots of code'
end

step 3 do
  puts 'Step 3 with lots of code'
end

step 4 do
  puts 'Step 4 with lots of code'
end
```

Launch them separately with `launch_steps.rb` :

```
# launch_steps.rb
require_relative 'define_steps'

launch_steps!
puts "-----------------"
launch_steps!(2,3)
```

It outputs :

```
Launching step 1
Step 1 with lots of code
Launching step 2
Step 2 with lots of code
Launching step 3
Step 3 with lots of code
Launching step 4
Step 4 with lots of code
-----------------
Launching step 2
Step 2 with lots of code
Launching step 3
Step 3 with lots of code
```

`launch_steps!` without parameters runs every defined step, `launch_steps!(min,max)` runs every step between `min` and `max`, `launch_steps!(min)` runs step `min` and every step after.

Comment: Having a little DSL here (domain specific language) does make this code pretty easy to follow. Nice!